# Trying to Create an Animated Vector Plot of Tangential Velocities

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

Wanted to see if anyone could help me out here.

I interested in seeing if it's possible to animate this vector plot I've created.

```
r[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
R2[x_, y_] := r[x, y]^2 + 1 + 2/r[x, y];
phidot[x_, y_] := If[r[x, y] >= 2, 2/((r[x, y])^3 + r[x, y] + 2), 0];
vx[x_, y_] := -y phidot[x, y];
vy[x_, y_] := x phidot[x, y];
VectorPlot[{vx[x, y], vy[x, y]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {y, -2 \[Pi],
2 \[Pi]}]
```

The equation used to create this vector field describes the speed at which space is drug by an extreme Kerr black hole.  As you get closer to the event horizon, r = 1, space is drug faster, hence the bigger vectors.  If possible, what I'd like to do is to get the vectors to circle around the origin in a similar manner, with some representation of their magnitude, at least relative to each other.  If anyone could offer some assistance, I'd really appreciate it.

As a bonus, it would be cool if any different colors or background were possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code as text instead of as an image so that people run it.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry guys.  Still new to this.  Learning the etiquette as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is similar to @Edmund's, except with the rotation angle dependent on the radius:

```
pts2 = Table[
   Table[{x Sin[t], x Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/(2 x)}], {x, 1, 8}];
a = Table[VectorPlot[{vx[x, y], vy[x, y]}, {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -2 π, 2 π}, 
    VectorPoints -> (Flatten[Table[RotationMatrix[ϕ/x].# & /@ pts2[[x]], {x, 1, 8}], 1])], {ϕ, 0, 2 π, π/20}];

Export["vectors.gif", a]
```

[image]

Edited to include an updated version in which it's easier to adjust the parameters:

```
numcircles = 20;
circlespacing = .5;
pointspacing = π/4;
frameinterval = π/20;

pts2 = Table[Table[{x Sin[t], x Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, pointspacing/x}], {x, 1, numcircles, circlespacing}];
a = Table[VectorPlot[{vx[x, y], vy[x, y]}, {x, -numcircles circlespacing, numcircles circlespacing}, {y, -numcircles circlespacing, numcircles circlespacing}, 
    VectorPoints -> (Flatten[
       Table[RotationMatrix[ϕ/n].# & /@ pts2[[n]], {n, Length[pts2]}], 1])], {ϕ, 0, 2 π - frameinterval, frameinterval}];
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me too it. Though I was going to use [`CirclePoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html) (+1).

Comment: @Edmund, yes `CirclePoints` would be better, or at least easier to read. It's not implemented in my ancient version of MMA (9)...

Comment: This is absolutely awesome and exactly what I've been looking for.  I have one additional question about it.  I have tried altering the code to include more vector points, 50, to be exact.  But when I make this change, the gif it creates doesn't actually have any motion.  Is there something else I need to do?
All I did was add a `VectorPoint -> 50,`

Comment: @Nathan, I wasn't exactly sure what you meant by 50 points (50 total?) so I updated the answer with a version that is more generalized - you can adjust the number of "circles", spacing between them, and interval of points... see if you get something suitable.

Comment: That about does it.  Thanks so much @MelaGo!  I'm sorry if my previous note wasn't very clear.  I'm pretty new to Mathematica, so I didn't even really know what I meant, specifically.  But this takes care of it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Nathan you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`RotationMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationMatrix.html) with the [`VectorPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPoints.html) option.

Using [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) and [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) to get an initial set of `VectorPoints`.

```
vpoints = Tuples[ConstantArray[Subdivide[-3 \[Pi], 3 \[Pi], 25], 2]];
```

Then with [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 VectorPlot[{vx[x, y], vy[x, y]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {y, -2 \[Pi], 2. \[Pi]},
  VectorPoints -> vpoints . RotationMatrix[r]],
 {{r, 0}, 0, -\[Pi]}
 ]
```

> [image]

As `VectorPlot` mentions in its documentation, it has the same options as [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html).  Look there for options on background colours and more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't 100% clear in my original post.  I have edited it to be a bit more clear.  Making the entire plot spin is nice, but what I'm really trying to do is to get each ring of vectors to spin with a magnitude relative to the magnitude of the other "rings".  So the vectors in the ring with the smallest value of r would spin the fastest and they would move more slowly as r increases.